# Are Hamiltonian Paths still NP-Complete if you are allowed to revisit vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

If you have a one or more Hamilitonian cycles in a graph, but you remove the restriction of only being able to visit a vertex once, then is it still an NP-Complete problem?

That is, is there no efficient way to find the shortest distance between all nodes?

Comment: These are completely different problems. The point of a Hamiltonian path is that you visit each node exactly once. If you want to solve the pairwise shortest distance problem, use something like [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

You can find shortest distances between all nodes just by calculating $A^n$, where $A$ is the graph adjacency matrix and $n$ is number of vertices. The time required is $O(n^4)$ if doing this naively.